# Bash script to check HTTP status before executing tests

Tags: bash, shell

Hi I am trying to execute specific tests only if application is up and running (I am using docker), I am trying to achieve this with the help of bash script. What I am expecting is I need to run a loop until I receive 200 status from application, once I receive 200 script should move ahead and execute the test.I am trying bash script as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
urlstatus=0
until [ $urlstatus -ne 200 ]; do
urlstatus=$(curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}' "http://localhost:8000/animals")
echo $urlstatus
done
```

Execute Test if application is up & running

Please let me know what is missing in the script.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please do mention what error you are getting here? or what is not working.

Comment: You should do `While True:` and then and if statement, when `urlstatus == 200` run your code and exit.

Comment: It's *always* not equal to 200 on the very first time it's tested -- you initialize the value to 0, so the loop doesn't need to run at all! If you want your loop to run even once, initialize `urlstatus=200`, not `urlstatus=0`.

Comment: that said, if you want to wait for 200, that's not what this code does; it waits until the value *isn't* 200.

Comment: Worry about that `^M` showing on the first (shebang) line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-ne` is the exact opposite of the test you actually want; to loop until the exit status is 200 you should have `-eq`, or even better (to avoid error messages from the comparison if a non-numeric value is present), `=`.

```
#!/bin/sh
fetchstatus() {
  curl \
    -o /dev/null \
    --silent \
    --head \
    --write-out '%{http_code}' \
    "http://localhost:8000/animals"
}

urlstatus=$(fetchstatus)          # initialize to actual value before we sleep even once
until [ "$urlstatus" = 200 ]; do  # until our result is success...
  sleep 1                         # wait a second...
  urlstatus=$(fetchstatus)        # then poll again.
done
```

---

But since `curl` can adjust its exit status to indicate whether a request was successful, you don't even need that. Use `--fail`, and you can branch directly:

```
#!/bin/sh
while :; do
  curl -sS --fail -o /dev/null "http://localhost:8000/animals") && break
  sleep 1 # actually give your server a little rest
done
```

The `&& break` means that we break out of the loop only if the request was successful; the `--fail` argument to curl means that it only returns success if the server returned a non-erroneous exit status (such as 200).

Comment: This could also just be `until curl -sS --fail -o /dev/null "http://localhost:8000/animals"); sleep 1; done`

Comment: Would 301 be considered a non-erroneous status?

Comment: @MiguelOrtiz, yes, unless you use `-L` and it redirects to something that fails. Frankly, though, any service that uses a 301 when it's not done initializing yet is misdesigned -- it's explicitly a "permanent redirection", not something that can be expected to go away after things finish booting.